# Checking for empty elements within my array - Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an element in my array that when I print out the value of that specific element I get an empty value.

```
puts my_listing[2].inspect
[]
```

When I check to see if that specific element is empty, using `empty?` it returns true:

```
puts my_listing[2].empty?
true
```

But when I cycle through the entire array, checking to see if `i` is empty, it doesn't find that particular element.

```
my_listing.each do |i|
    if i.empty?
        puts i
    end
end
```

`i` (in this case `2`) is never printed to the screen.

Why is that?

Basically, I am trying to get rid of all the elements in the array that are empty (in this case the element at index `2`) but I am not sure how to even get at those elements.

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh please iterate like this

```
       my_listing.each_with_index do |i,index|
          if i.blank?
             puts index.inspect
          end
       end
```

It give you index of array which will be empty or nil.

Comment: the method `.blank?` doesn't work, but `.empty?` does. Thanks.

Comment: FYI: this is the error I get when I do `.blank?` - `NoMethodError: undefined method 'blank?' for []:Nokogiri::XML::NodeSet`. I am using Nokogiri and am storing a node in an array.

Comment: How do I pop an element that is empty? I tried doing `i.pop` in the each, but that didn't work. Neither did `index.pop`. Thoughts?

Comment: Never mind, I tried `reject!` like @jessehz suggested and it worked beautifully.

Comment: In case you were wondering - `.blank?` is a Rails extension method which checks for `.nil?` and `.empty?` (at least as far as I remember). If you're not in Rails then it would explain why it doesn't work!

Answer (score 7):

You're not seeing anything printed because you forgot to use #inspect
You could also just have written:

```
my_listing.each do |i|
    i.empty? and p i
end
```

To remove empty elements, you can do the following:

```
my_array = [[1],[2],[],[4]]

p my_array.reject(&:empty?) # => [[1], [2], [4]]
```

reject calls #empty? on all the elements and removes the ones which are empty